# simulate blinking of a button android

Tags: android, timer

i want to make my                                                              button switch it's background color thrice a second between two colors - 
**btn_tp_dark** and **btn_tp_light**

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        private View Button;
        public void run() {
            Button = (View) findViewById(R.id.filmTransparent11);
            Button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_tp_dark);
        }
    }, 300);
```

which is supposed to simulate a blinking effect but i dont know how to achieve this.

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/filmTransparent11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="11"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:onClick="next1" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother using a `Timer` in android. Instead use a `Handler`.

You can create a looping task like this:

```
final Button button = (View) findViewById(R.id.filmTransparent11);
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable changeBackground = new Runnable() {
  private int i;
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Set background based on task execution counter
    if (++i % 2 == 0) {
      button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_tp_light);
    } else {
      button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_tp_dark);
    }

    // Repeat task
    handler.postDelayed(this, 300);
  }
};

// Initiate the task
handler.postDelayed(changeBackground, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve it is using the [ValueAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#addUpdateListener(android.animation.ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener)), with an [ArgInterpolator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ArgbEvaluator.html). The duration of the Animation is 300ms, and you probably want to use `ValueAnimator.INFINITE` and `ValueAnimator.REVERSE` as repeat mode